# Mailchimp applies the table's border in the whole template design

Tags: html, css, html-table, mailchimp, newsletter

Mailchimp is so frustrating. I'm trying to make a campaign with the template that I did. It's supposed to look like this:

[image: template design]

BUT when I'm trying to paste a table that I copied from google sheets, it's looking like this

[image: template with border]

How do I fix it? How can I make the borders disappear every time I'm going to paste a table?

If you're wondering this is the source code (I removed the content because it's classified and it exceeded the 30,000 characters limit):

```
<style type="text/css"><!--td {border: 1px solid #ccc;}br {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}-->
</style>
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" dir="ltr">
<colgroup>
    <col width="277" />
    <col width="100" />
    <col width="100" />
    <col width="113" />
    <col width="114" />
    <col width="49" />
    <col width="79" />
    <col width="2" />
    <col width="100" />
    <col width="100" />
</colgroup>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;AS OF: 8/29/16&quot;}">AS OF: 8/29/16</td>
        <td colspan="6" data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;DIGITAL CARDS / CODES\n Official Pins or Scans with Text&quot;}" rowspan="1">DIGITAL CARDS / CODES<br />
        Official Pins or Scans with Text</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2" data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;PHYSICAL CARDS\n Free shipping on 500+ units&quot;}" rowspan="1">PHYSICAL CARDS<br />
        Free shipping on 500+ units</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2" data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;&lt; 100 Units&quot;}" rowspan="1">&lt; 100 Units</td>
        <td colspan="2" data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;100+ Units\n Call/Email for pricing on 1000+ units per item&quot;}" rowspan="1">100+ Units<br />
        Call/Email for pricing on 1000+ units per item</td>
        <td colspan="2" data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;Format&quot;}" rowspan="1">Format</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2" data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;Call/Email for pricing\n on 1000+ units per item&quot;}" rowspan="1">Call/Email for pricing<br />
        on 1000+ units per item</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;Unit Cost&quot;}">&nbsp;</td>
        <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;% Off MSRP&quot;}">&nbsp;</td>
        <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;Unit Cost&quot;}">&nbsp;</td>
        <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;% Off MSRP&quot;}">&nbsp;</td>
        <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;Pins&quot;}">&nbsp;</td>
        <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;Scans + Text&quot;}">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;Unit Cost&quot;}">&nbsp;</td>
        <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;% Off MSRP&quot;}">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-sheets-numberformat="[null,4,&quot;\&quot;$\&quot;#,##0&quot;,1]" data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:10}">&nbsp;</td>
        <td data-sheets-numberformat="[null,4,&quot;\&quot;$\&quot;#,##0.00&quot;,1]" data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:9.15}">&nbsp;</td>
        <td data-sheets-numberformat="[null,3,&quot;0.00%&quot;,1]" data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:0.085}">&nbsp;</td>
        <td data-sheets-numberformat="[null,4,&quot;\&quot;$\&quot;#,##0.00&quot;,1]" data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:9.1}">&nbsp;</td>
        <td data-sheets-numberformat="[null,3,&quot;0.00%&quot;,1]" data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:0.09}">&nbsp;</td>
        <td data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;\u25cf&quot;}">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td data-sheets-numberformat="[null,4,&quot;\&quot;$\&quot;#,##0.00&quot;,1]" data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:9.1}">&nbsp;</td>
        <td data-sheets-numberformat="[null,3,&quot;0.00%&quot;,1]" data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:0.09}">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-sheets-numberformat="[null,4,&quot;\&quot;$\&quot;#,##0&quot;,1]">&nbsp;</td>
        <td data-sheets-numberformat="[null,4,&quot;\&quot;$\&quot;#,##0.00&quot;,1]">&nbsp;</td>
        <td data-sheets-numberformat="[null,3,&quot;0.00%&quot;,1]">&nbsp;</td>
        <td data-sheets-numberformat="[null,4,&quot;\&quot;$\&quot;#,##0.00&quot;,1]">&nbsp;</td>
        <td data-sheets-numberformat="[null,3,&quot;0.00%&quot;,1]">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" dir="ltr">` remove `border=1`

Comment: FYI : MailChimp is not so frustrating. :)

Comment: @GokulShinde Hi I tried it but the border is still there :(

Comment: @MûhámmàdYäsårK lol it is though their suggestions didn't work :( plus before, I used a responsive template from github for mailchimp and sometimes it just suddenly won't work... No idea why 'cause I didn't even change anything. So now I'm using their pre-made templates and I'm having this issue :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:** set each `<table>` to `border="0"`

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" dir="ltr">
```

**Step 2:** delete the commented-out `td {border: 1px solid #ccc;}`

You should now have no borders anywhere, so go back and add only the borders you want with inline styles on either `<td>`s (best) or `<table>`s. Eg:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" dir="ltr">
    <tr>
        <td style="border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;">
            content
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This should produce an email with no unintentional borders anywhere. I'm not sure what pasting from Google Sheets is like, but you'll want to edit the HTML in this way to make sure it displays correctly.

Comment: Thank you for this! Does this mean I have to do this every time I post it? This is troublesome for the person who does the campaign he does not know anything about html lol

Comment: Yes, it sounds like pasting a table from google sheets does not produce email-friendly markup. So every time this is done, the code will need to be cleaned up. If you do this often, perhaps a few find/replace operations will help?

Answer (score 3):

table border applied change `border="0"`

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" dir="ltr">
```

Comment: This answer should work. You can also delete the commented-out `td {border: 1px solid #ccc;}`, just to make sure MailChimp doesn't accidentally apply it.

Comment: Hi I just tried this but it didn't work :( the border is still there

Comment: @TedGoas Hi I removed the commented-out td and it worked! BUT it also removed the borders from the actual table :(

Comment: I added my own answer that hopefully encapsulates everything.